# Spring Data JPA implementing Persistable results in InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement `Persistable` to delegate entity state detection to the interface and to finally minimize the number of db queries while saving / updating entities. After implementing I get `InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist` while trying to update existing entities.

These exceptions occur for every class while using the Spring Data Repository `save` method. Code is working fine without `Persistable` but with a lot of more queries.

Overall the case is to get rid of many queries generated while using `Spring Data JPA save` method. Without implementation, all methods are working Ok.

This is `Persistable` implementation for a superClass based on the [Spring Data JPA docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-persistence)

Anybody has any idea on what's going on here?

Implementation of `Persistable` according to the docs.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Persistable<UUID> {


    public BaseEntity () {

    }

    public BaseEntity(UUID id, Long version, Timestamp createdDate, Timestamp lastModifiedDate) {
        this.id = id;
        this.version = version;
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false )
    private UUID id;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Timestamp createdDate;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp lastModifiedDate;

    public int hashCode () {
        return Objects.hash(this.id);
    }

    public boolean equals (Object that) {
        return this == that || that instanceof BaseEntity && Objects.equals(this.id, ((BaseEntity) that).id);
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Transient
    private boolean isNew = true;

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }

    @PrePersist
    @PostLoad
    void markNotNew() {
        this.isNew = false;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Timestamp getCreatedDate() {
        return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(Timestamp createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Timestamp getLastModifiedDate() {
        return lastModifiedDate;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedDate(Timestamp lastModifiedDate) {
        this.lastModifiedDate = lastModifiedDate;
    }
}
```

Example entity class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Question extends BaseEntity {

    private String contents;
    private String mainTech;
    private String specificTech;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SkillLevel skillLevel;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Answer> answers = new ArrayList<>();

    @Builder
    public Question(UUID id,
                    Long version,
                    Timestamp createdDate,
                    Timestamp lastModifiedDate,
                    java.lang.String contents,
                    String mainTech,
                    java.lang.String specificTech,
                    ArrayList<Answer> answers,
                    SkillLevel skillLevel) {
        super(id, version, createdDate, lastModifiedDate);
        this.contents = contents;
        this.mainTech = mainTech;
        this.specificTech = specificTech;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.skillLevel = skillLevel;
    }

    public void addAnswer(Answer answer) {
        this.getAnswers().add(answer);
        answer.setQuestion(this);
    }

    public void removeAnswer(Answer answer) {
        this.getAnswers().remove(answer);
        answer.setQuestion(null);
    }

    @Override
    public java.lang.String toString() {
        return "Question{" +
                "id='" + this.getId() + '\'' +
                "contents='" + contents + '\'' +
                ", mainTech=" + mainTech +
                ", specificTech='" + specificTech + '\'' +
                ", skillLevel=" + skillLevel +
                ", answers=" + answers.size() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Service class

```
@Service
public class QuestionServiceImpl implements QuestionService {

    private final QuestionRepository questionRepository;
    private final QuestionMapper mapper;
    private final EntityManagerFactory emf;

    public QuestionServiceImpl(
            QuestionRepository questionRepository,
            EntityManagerFactory emf,
            QuestionMapper mapper
    ) {
        this.questionRepository = questionRepository;
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.emf = emf;
    }

    @Override
    public QuestionDto saveOrUpdate(QuestionDto questionDto) {
        Question save = questionRepository.save(mapper.dtoToObject(questionDto, contextProvider()));
        return mapper.objectToDto(save, contextProvider());
    }


    public QuestionDto findByUuId(UUID uuid) {
        Question question = emf.createEntityManager().createQuery("select q from Question q " +
                "left join fetch q.answers " +
                "where q.id = :uuid", Question.class)
                .setParameter("uuid", uuid)
                .getSingleResult();
        return mapper.objectToDto(question, contextProvider());
    }

//More code ...
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface QuestionRepository extends JpaRepository<Question, UUID> {

    @Override
    List<Question> findAll();

    @Override
    <S extends Question> S save(S s);

    @Override
    Optional<Question> findById(UUID uuid);

    Question findByContentsEquals(String contents);

    List<Question> findAllByMainTechAndSpecificTech(String mainTech, java.lang.String specificTech);

    List<Question> findAllByMainTech(String mainTech);

    List<Question> findAllByMainTechAndSkillLevel(String mainTech, SkillLevel skillLevel);

    List<Question> findAllByMainTechAndSkillLevelAndSpecificTech(String mainTech, SkillLevel skillLevel, String specificTech);

}
```

Test case

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class QuestionServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    QuestionRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    QuestionServiceImpl service;

    @Autowired
    QuestionMapper mapper;


    QuestionDto question1;
    QuestionDto question2;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

        question1 = QuestionDto.builder()
                .answers(new ArrayList<>())
                .contents("testQuestion1")
                .skillLevel(SkillLevel.ENTRY)
                .specificTech("Core")
                .mainTech("Java")
                .build();

        question2 = QuestionDto.builder()
                .answers(new ArrayList<>())
                .contents("testQuestion1")
                .skillLevel(SkillLevel.ENTRY)
                .specificTech("Core")
                .mainTech("Java")
                .build();

        assertAll(
                () -> assertThat(question1.getContents()).isEqualTo(question2.getContents())
        );
    }

    @Test
    public void callingSaveOrUpdateMultipleTimesShouldAlwaysReturnSingleEntity() {
        // Given
        QuestionDto savedQuestion1 = service.saveOrUpdate(question1);
        System.out.println("first save 1" + savedQuestion1);
        QuestionDto savedQuestion2 = service.saveOrUpdate(question2);
        System.out.println("first save 2" + savedQuestion2);

        QuestionDto savedQuestion1a = service.saveOrUpdate(savedQuestion1);
        QuestionDto savedQuestion1b = service.saveOrUpdate(savedQuestion1a);
        QuestionDto savedQuestion1c = service.saveOrUpdate(savedQuestion1b);
        System.out.println("last save 1");
        QuestionDto savedQuestion2a = service.saveOrUpdate(savedQuestion2);
        QuestionDto savedQuestion2b = service.saveOrUpdate(savedQuestion2a);
        service.saveOrUpdate(savedQuestion2b);
        System.out.println("last save 2");
        // When
        QuestionDto searchResult = service.findByUuId(savedQuestion1.getId());


        List<QuestionDto> all = service.findAll();
        // Then
        assertAll(
                () -> assertThat(searchResult).isNotNull(),
                () -> assertThat(searchResult.getId()).isEqualTo(savedQuestion1.getId()),
                () -> assertThat(all.size()).isEqualTo(2),
                () -> assertThat(all.get(0).getId()).isEqualTo(savedQuestion1.getId()),
                () -> assertThat(all.get(1).getId()).isEqualTo(savedQuestion2.getId())
        );
    }
}
```

Error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.github.pawelbialas.testgeneratorapp.entity.question.model.Question; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.github.pawelbialas.testgeneratorapp.entity.question.model.Question

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:319)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.github.pawelbialas.testgeneratorapp.entity.question.service.QuestionServiceImpl.saveOrUpdate(QuestionServiceImpl.java:38)
    at com.github.pawelbialas.testgeneratorapp.entity.question.service.QuestionServiceImplTest.callingSaveOrUpdateMultipleTimesShouldAlwaysReturnSingleEntity(QuestionServiceImplTest.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.github.pawelbialas.testgeneratorapp.entity.question.model.Question
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:702)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:688)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:314)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:554)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 72 more
```

Comment: (1) Why do you feel you need a custom definition of `Persistable` with `@GeneratedValue`-annotated id? The caption above the sample code reads: 'A base class for entities **with manually assigned identifiers**' (2) does it work if you annotate the test with `@Transactional`? (3) How does the `mapper.dtoToObject(...)` line handle `Question.answers`?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you feel you need a custom definition of `Persistable` with `@GeneratedValue`-annotated id when the caption above the sample code reads: 'A base class for entities with **manually assigned identifiers**'?

Implementing `Persistable` that way means that whenever you create the entity object by mapping from the DTO, it will be considered new by Spring Data. Consequently, `JpaRepository.save()` will call `EntityManager.persist()` internally. This implies all the subsequent calls to `service.saveOrUpdate(...)` on a `QuestionDto` in your test (after the initial one) will try to persist existing objects (instead of merging them into the context), hence the error.

If you want the custom `Persistable` implementation to work, you would need separate `save` and `update` methods where `update` looks sth like:

```
questionRepository.findById(questionDto.getId())
.ifPresent(dbQuestionVersion ->
    mapper.mapDtoOntoObject(questionDto, dbQuestionVersion, contextProvider()))`
```

I'm guessing that's not what you want, though.

Comment: Hello @crizzis! The main motivation is to get rid of the surplus SELECTs while using the `save()` provided by Spring Data JPA by delegating entity state detection to Persistable methods and field. In my case, all id's are generated and the mapper is converting entities to DTO 1:1 - I'm using map struct - meaning that all properties taken from saved DTO are put into another Entity object before saving, but I must check how the mapper treats 'isNew', so that could be the case when entity mapped from DTO gets `isNew` by default.

Comment: Not sure I follow, *which* `SELECT` done by Hibernate do you feel is superflous? Hibernate needs to issue a `SELECT` as part of `merge`, that's just [the way it works](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate). Also, Hibernate knows nothing about `Persistable` since it is a Spring Data interface. Tinkering with `Persistable` will not affect the way `merge` works in any way

Comment: If you really insist on eliminating the `SELECT`, [this article suggests](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-optimize-the-merge-operation-using-update-while-batching-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) that `session.update()` does not issue one. You'll need to customize the `CrudRepository.save` method or add your own, though. And, for new entities, the default `isNew()` implementation should result in a `persist()` instead of a `merge()`, thus already avoiding any `SELECT`s whatsoever

Comment: Thank You @crizzis! Very nice concept from Vlad. As for this moment `Persistable` is working by making it simply simpler with `public boolean isNew() {
        return null == this.getId();
    }`. SQL logs look pretty the same now, so I guess this is the desired behavior, and shouldn't be played with this much I think.

Comment: Well, yeah, that implementation is identical to the default one, so it comes as no surprise the logs look the same

Answer (score 0):

Below code not available in BaseEntiy. When ever you are OneToMany or ManyToOne you should declare in both entity

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "foreign_key")
private Question   question;
```

Comment: Declare *what* in both entities?